# How to find which user killed my program?

Tags: logging, sudo, user, kill

I am running a long running program on a Linux server. Many other users are also running their programs on this server. All of us have sudo permissions.

Assume a mischievous user kills my running program, say using `sudo kill` or `sudo pkill`. How do I find out which is this user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Paul's answer is correct, in that evidence could be eliminated, that doesn't mean that the evidence is eliminated.  Many more people know about sudo, compared to the number of people who know about what logs to purge (if they would even bother).

On my system, every time sudo is used, the entire command line is stored in a log.  I imagine your system may do the same.  On OpenBSD, this is /var/log/authlog while on a Debian system, it is /var/log/auth.log

If you don't know which file stores such information, try running a sudo command.  (It doesn't matter what you do with sudo: even `echo` would be sufficient.  The purpose is to modify the logs that get modified when sudo is used.)  Then use

> `ls -ltr /var/log/*auth*`

or

> `ls -ltr /var/log | tail`

in order to find recently-modified files.

Answer (score 1):

If you all have `sudo`, then there is no guaranteed way to keep evidence of a killed process, as any evidence could be removed with the same level of permission.

You can use the `auditd` [auditing daemon](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/36278) to track specific syscalls, such as kill.

Obviously a root user could just stop the audit daemon first, then delete the logs.  So you'd want to export logs externally.

A better approach would be to managed sudo better, giving each user only the access they need.  General users almost never need full root access, and you can use sudo to give a subset of permissions.

Comment: Assume there is no malicious user, but merely an ignorant user who is running sudo kill. How do I find out who this person is?

Comment: @AshwinNanjappa: Sudo logs everything to syslog.